# Setting System V message queue size on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, ipc, message-queue

I am currently using System V message queues on Mac OSX and am having trouble setting the queue size to a value larger than 2048 bytes. Here is a compile-able example `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  // get a message queue id
  int id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT|0600);
  if (-1 == id)
      exit(1);

  // get message queue data structure
  struct msqid_ds buf;
  if (-1 == msgctl(id, IPC_STAT, &buf))
      exit(1);
  printf("size is %lu bytes\n", buf.msg_qbytes);

  // set new buffer size
  buf.msg_qbytes = 2750;
  printf("setting size to %lu bytes\n", buf.msg_qbytes);
  if (-1 == msgctl(id, IPC_SET, &buf))
      exit(1);

  // check updated message queue data structure
  if (-1 == msgctl(id, IPC_STAT, &buf))
      exit(1);
  printf("size is %lu bytes\n", buf.msg_qbytes);
}
```

Compile with:

```
clang -Wall -pedantic -o test test.c
```

And run with:

```
sudo ./test
```

Note: You have run the above code with `sudo` to ensure that the `msgcntl` calls succeed.

The output of this program snippet is:

```
size is 2048 bytes
setting size to 2750 bytes
size is 2048 bytes
```

Why isn't the queue size getting changed?

**EDIT:**
The output of `ipcs -Q` shows:

```
IPC status from <running system> as of Tue Dec  1 10:06:39 PST 2015
msginfo:
    msgmax:  16384  (max characters in a message)
    msgmni:     40  (# of message queues)
    msgmnb:   2048  (max characters in a message queue)
    msgtql:     40  (max # of messages in system)
    msgssz:      8  (size of a message segment)
    msgseg:   2048  (# of message segments in system)
```

Can `msgmnb` be made larger, or am I stuck?

Comment: Try running `ipcs -Q` to see if there is a maximum size.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I updated the question with the output of `ipcs -Q`.

Comment: I have never tried this on OSX, and I don't know if it works or may cause problems, but I guess you would do something like `sysctl -w kernel.msgmnb=2000000`

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Yeah.. unfortunately `sysctl -A | grep msgmnb` returns nothing. I don't see anything in there relating to System V message queues :(

Comment: on ubuntu linux 14.04, the parameter to `ipcs` of `-Q` is not valid  however, a lower case `-q` is valid, but then requires a valid queue identifier

Comment: @user3629249 - This is an Mac OSX problem. System V message queues work fine on Linux.

Comment: This post is somewhat dated, but have a look anyway... http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Jan/msg00033.html Maybe have a look at ZeroMQ...

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Yeah... that is what I was afraid of. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that OS X does not permit to increase the message queue size. The system V implementation is old and not documented at all. I also found strange that the define MSGMNB, MSGMAX are missing from message.h whereas you can find it in Linux and other Unix implementation.

I also find this:

> OS X is the worst of the lot. Each queue is limited to 2048 bytes and
>   OS X silently ignores attempts to increase this (just like FreeBSD).
>   To add insult to injury, there appears to be no way to increase this
>   limit short of recompiling the kernel. I'm guessing at this based on
>   the Darwin message queue limits. (http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/)

The document was updated on Sept 2014 and confirms the post in the apple mailing list:

> http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Jan/msg00033.html

Pointed out by @Mark Setchell in the comment.

Also, a recent Ruby Wrapper implementation is not supported on OS X as the author states that:

> The messages are handled by the kernel of your computer. Not all
>   kernels have support for POSIX message queues, a notably example is
>   Darwin (OS X). Darwin implements the older System V IPC API.
>   (https://github.com/Sirupsen/posix-mqueue)

On the web there are other sources (mostly old) that indicate that there is no way other than recompiling the kernel to increase the message queue limits.

**UPDATE**: Apple's position is to discourage the use of System V IPC [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/BSD/BSD.html):

> Some System V primitives are supported, but their use is discouraged
>   in favor of POSIX equivalents.

Side suggestion, add:
 `msgctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL);` 
at the end of the test code, someone (like me, sigh!) could forget that each queue must be closed.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no POSIX equivalent for System V message queues on Mac because Posix queues are not supported at all.

Comment: @dinkelk Yes but oddly, as you can see, that is what is reported in the developer page

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble finding Mac-specific documentation, but [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgget.html) that when a message queue is created via `msgget()`, its "`msg_qbytes` shall be set equal to the system limit."  The BSD manual page for `msgget()` says the same, and that's OS X's closest relative.  For what it's worth, Linux man pages seem universally to agree.

That's all pretty consistent in indicating that if your initial queue size is not large enough then you are hosed.  You can (maybe) shrink it, but you cannot grow it beyond its initial value.

Answer (score -1):

the man page for `msgctl()`

the field the code is changing is the *current* number of bytes in the queue and not the maximum number of bytes in the queue.

Suggest looking at: `msglen_t msg_qbytes` which is the maximum number of bytes *allowed* in the queue.

Comment: If you look at my code, it is actually changing `msg_qbytes`.